# What is the reason that an empty string evaluates to false in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Why is it that an empty string evaluates to false in JavaScript. I know Douglas Crockford has spoken quite a bit about truthy and falsy in javascript but this still surprised me:

```
if("")
    alert("you will never see this");
```

Anyone know what the basis of this behavior is. Is it implemented in this way according to the ECMAScript specifications? I'm curious.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because it has nothing in it. An empty string is a false value in many languages. This is standard according to the specification.

> The result is  false if the argument is the empty String (its length is zero); 
>   otherwise the result is true

— section 9.2 of [Ecma-262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf)

Comment: How to explain `'' === false;` being false then?

Comment: Because the point of `===` is that it doesn't do type conversion and most false values are not `false` (`false` is a false value that is `false`).

Comment: @KooiInc: Strict comparison checkes the type too. A string is not a boolean value, hence they ar not equal.